# How to get docker-compose container to see Redis host?

Tags: go, docker-compose, redis

I have this simple `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  bot:
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: .
    links:
      - redis
    depends_on:
      - redis
  redis:
    image: redis:7.0.0-alpine
    ports:
     - "6379:6379"
    environment:
     - REDIS_REPLICATION_MODE=master
    restart: always
    volumes: 
      - cache:/data
    command: redis-server
volumes:
  cache:
    driver: local
```

This is how the `bot` (in Go) connects to `redis`:

```
import "github.com/go-redis/redis/v8"

func setRedisClient() {
  rdb = redis.NewClient(&redis.Options{
    Addr:     "redis:6379",
    Password: "",
    DB:       0,
  })
}
```

`bot` Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.18.3-alpine3.16
WORKDIR /go/src/bot-go
COPY . .
RUN go build .
RUN ./bot-go
```

But when I run `docker-compose up --build` I always get:

```
panic: dial tcp: lookup redis on 192.168.65.5:53: no such host
```

`redis` host is never seen no matter what changes I make to the host or to `docker-compose` file.

The app does work without Docker when I configure the client to local.

What I am doing wrong exactly?

Comment: Please include os version you are running on your computer. There may be some issues for docker itself. This is not always your fault.

Comment: @DiptoMondal Good to know that Docker version matters. But Kaleab solved it for me. Thank you!

Comment: Yeap there can be some issues in docker-desktop for apple silicon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the bot-go image never stops building. Change `RUN ./bot-go` to `CMD [ "./bot-go" ]` in the Dockerfile and everything will work fine.